# Populating an array using a FOR loop and a function

Tags: julia

I was expecting that the following code would populate E with random 1's and 0's, but that does not happen. I cannot figure out why.

```
Pkg.add("StatsBase")
using StatsBase

function randomSample(items,weights)
    sample(items, Weights(weights))
end



n = 10
periods = 100

p = [ones(n,periods)*0.5]
E = fill(NaN, (n,periods))

for i in 1:periods
    for ii in 1:n
        E(ii,i) = randomSample([1 0],[(p(ii,i)), 1 - p(ii,i)])
    end
end
E
```

Comment: Unlike MATLAB, indexing is done with brackets in Julia not with parentheses. Be careful with the brackets, though, `[ones(5, 10)]` will give you an `Array` of `Array`(s). In MATLAB, however, it makes no difference to add as many surrounding brackets as possible: the result will be just a matrix.

Comment: Since you are already using `fill` to initialize `E`, why not do the same with `p`:? That is, `p = fill(0.5, (n, periods))`. This is more efficient (and reasonable) than first creating a matrix of ones, and then creating a second matrix by multiplying the first one with 0.5.

Answer (score 2):

The statement:

```
E(ii,i) = randomSample([1 0],[(p(ii,i)), 1 - p(ii,i)])
```

defines a local function `E` and is not an assignment operation to a matrix `E`. Use

```
E[ii,i] = randomSample([1, 0],[p[ii,i], 1 - p[ii,i]])
```

(I have fixed additional errors in your code so please check out the differences)

and for it to run you should also write:

```
p = ones(n,periods)*0.5
```